# Setting up a section using shapefile.Reader

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I would like to open some shapefile with `shapefile.Reader` but I would like to see some part of it, for example 10000-20000 records. How to set up a section? I can't find that in documentation.

```
with shapefile.Reader(shapefile_path) as shp:
```

Comment: Shapefile is direct-access capable (through `.shx`). Most drivers should support direct access.  But it's trivial to just add a counter and `continue` until the record arrives, then `break` when you're done.

Answer (score 5):

`shapefile.Reader` doesn't support indexing. It loads all data to the memory. After using `shapefile.Reader("file_path")` you can get a specific range of features in different ways.

1. Using `itertools` as in Thomas's answer.

   ```
   import shapefile
   import itertools

   shapefile_path = "C:/path/to/shapefile.shp"
   shp = shapefile.Reader(shapefile_path)

   section = [s for s in  itertools.islice(shp, 10000, 20000)]
   ```
2. Using your own method that uses `iterShapeRecords` method which returns a generator.

   ```
   import shapefile

   shapefile_path = "C:/path/to/shapefile.shp"
   shp = shapefile.Reader(shapefile_path)

   def slice(shp, start, end):    
       section = []
       for i, row in enumerate(shp.iterShapeRecords()):
           if start <= i < end:
               section.append(row)
           elif i > end:
               break
       return section

   section = slice(shp, 10000, 20000)
   ```
3. Using `shapeRecords` method which returns a list, then, you can slice it.

   ```
   import shapefile

   shapefile_path = "C:/path/to/shapefile.shp"
   shp = shapefile.Reader(shapefile_path)

   section = shp.shapeRecords()[10000:20000]
   ```

(1) and (2) have almost the same performance. (3) has low performance for a big dataset but is easy to use for a small one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python `itertools` for this purpose

```
import json
import itertools
import shapefile


with shapefile.Reader("ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp") as shp: 
     # print(shp.fields) # Fields info
     # print(len(shp)) # To count to help decide range
     features = []
     for s in itertools.islice(shp, 10000, 20000): # Loop only on a subset of features
     # for s in shp: # Swap code comment with above line to loop on all features
          features.append({
              "type": "Feature",
              "geometry": s.shape.__geo_interface__,
              "properties": s.record.as_dict()
          })

# Write to GeoJSON file
with open('demo.geojson', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features}, outfile)
```